# This python bot won't let me run it

Tags: python

It keeps saying:

Exception has occurred: TypeError
'int' object is not iterable

```
import pyautogui,time
time.sleep(3)

f = 10000
i = 0
for i in f:
    pyautogui.typewrite(i)
    pyautogui.press("space")
```

Comment: have you read the python doc page about `for in`

Answer (score 3):

If you want the integers from `0`..`f` then you'd use `range`

```
for i in range(f):
```